# Do I have to buy old hardware if I want to use an old Linux Kernel?

Tags: linux-kernel, boot, hardware, hardware-compatibility

I don't currently have access to a computer to boot my ssd and add drivers before trying new hardware. I want to buy a new mini pc with a processor released this year but my OS is rhel 8.6 and I'm worried that it won't boot. It's kernal was released in 2018 so, do I have to buy an old processor from 2017 to ensure it will boot or, can I buy the latest processor?

Comment: The problem is not just the processor, but mostly the motherboard chipset. If the kernel does not recognize the processor model, it might run inefficiently; but if it does not recognize the SATA controller in the chipset, it cannot complete the boot process at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The RHEL 8 kernel is based on a 2018 kernel, but many features and drivers are backported to it regularly. Recent hardware is supported, so you don’t need to buy an old processor. For example, [Intel Gen 12 CPUs](https://catalog.redhat.com/hardware/components/detail/141687) are supported in RHEL 8.6 and later, [Gen 13 CPUs](https://catalog.redhat.com/hardware/components/detail/223747) in RHEL 8.8 and later.

You can check [certified components](https://catalog.redhat.com/hardware/search?type=Component%7CCPU%20Collection%7CNetwork%20Adapter%20Collection) before purchase. Given the level of integration in modern systems (and not-so-modern ones), if a given generation of CPU is certified, the associated chipsets (including SATA controllers etc.) will be supported too.

Comment: whether an old upstream kernel with years of backports, fixes and potentially big-RHEL-customer-specific patches on top is still an "old" kernel is worth discussing. Of course, RHEL keeps most kernel APIs intact (so that e.g. your hard drive controller driver still builds), but it's not like it stays the same piece of software. But yeah, from a user's point of view, latest RHEL 8.x should run on pretty modern hardware.